# Getting the error while creating the maven project

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I am getting the error while creating the maven project .

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - CoreException: Could not get the value for parameter compilerId for plugin execution default-compile: PluginResolutionException: Plugin 
     org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to transfer junit:junit:jar:3.8.2 from 
     https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has 
     elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact junit:junit:jar:3.8.2 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): 
     repo.maven.apache.org
    - CoreException: Could not get the value for parameter compilerId for plugin execution default-testCompile: PluginResolutionException: 
     Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to transfer junit:junit:jar:3.8.2 
     from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central 
     has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact junit:junit:jar:3.8.2 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): 
     repo.maven.apache.org
```

Above error message shown in pom.xml first line -

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
```

Comment: this seems to be a connection issue. either caused by your internet connection or a missing proxy configuration? If you fixed the connection issue, you may delete the junit folder from the local maven repository to make sure maven retries the download (the messages state something about a reattempt and an update interval)

Comment: It's not a connection issue as I checked the internet and no junit folder deleted from maven repository .

Comment: Any other way to remove this error ?